# QueryService createSpecification compilation error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jhipster

jhipster version 5.0.2

It compiles and runs correctly, but the Eclipse is complaining about a missing class called Move_ for my Move entity.  Offending code in MoveQueryService.java follows.

How can I get Eclipse to stop reporting this error?  Thanks!

```
private Specification<Move> createSpecification(MoveCriteria criteria) {
        Specification<Move> specification = Specification.where(null);
        if (criteria != null) {
            if (criteria.getId() != null) {
                specification = specification.and(buildSpecification(criteria.getId(), Move_.id));
        }
```

Comment: I tried adding build/generated/source/apt to the source path but that just produced even more errors.  E.g. AbstractAuditingEntity cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Adding build/classes/java/main as a Class folder to the Build path resolves the issue, but that feels like the wrong solution.

Comment: You used maven? If you are using Maven, you need to activate the IDE profile in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I solve this adding a new "Source Folder" into de project pointing to "target/generated-sources/annotations" into de project folder.

I dont' know if this is the best solution, but it work for me.